# Jenkins job with different configuration?

Tags: jenkins

I am refactoring a single "too" big multiple module maven Jenkins job to about 10 smaller maven Jenkins jobs (one parent maven module with childs).

I like to run a single maven job every 2 hours without the tests and source code analyzers like PMD and Checkstyle, and once a day during the night I want to run it with the tests and source code analyzers.

I am not sure how to do this best. 
Jenkins is very flexible and I read the Jenkins O'Reilly book, but I am stil not sure how to do it :(
I was thinking about using the Maven Jenkins plugin with job inheritances, but I still end up with many jobs I guess. Is this the way to go ?

Please some advice?
- Ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trick I use is to set a property for build phase for any plugin that I want to disable and set it manually in jenkins. for example see the pmd plugin below:

See  ${pmd.phase}

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
            <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
            <linkXref>false</linkXref>
            <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
            <failurePriority>1</failurePriority>
            <rulesets>
                <ruleset>${pom.basedir}/pmd-rulesets.xml</ruleset>
            </rulesets>
         </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <phase>${pmd.phase}</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now define

```
<properties>
    <pmd.phase>none</pmd.phase>
</properties>
```

In jenkins set the Goals and options field to clean install -Dpmd.phase=validate

The command line property overrides defined one so pmd will run only if the -Dpmd.phase=validate is present.

Comment: Thanks, but how to you enabled/disable the pmd/checkstyle plugin's?

Comment: clean install -Dpmd.phase=none will disable it and clean install -Dpmd.phase=validate will enable it. Is that what you were asking.